# SQL Server - stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. According to the parser, the syntax is OK. However, when I try to execute the stored procedure and pass actual values, the following error comes up:

> Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure
>   SaveOneTimeDonation, Line 0
>   Procedure or function 'SaveOneTimeDonation' expects parameter '@donation', which was not
>   supplied.

Strange enough, the data is actually inserted into the table so I don't know why it is displaying this error.

How can I solve this problem please?  Here is the code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROC [dbo].[SaveOneTimeDonation]
  @donation float,
  @date nvarchar
AS
   INSERT INTO OneTime_Trans(Donation, Trans_Date) VALUES (@donation, @date)

   exec SaveOneTimeDonation
```

Comment: how exactly are you calling SaveOneTimeDonation? Also why is SaveOneTimeDonation calling itself?

Comment: Side note: if it's a `@date` - why is it defined as a `nvarchar` datatype?? Also: by not specifying any **length**, you're getting a `nvarchar(1)` - 1 character long........

Comment: If it's a date - define it as such! `@date DATE` - if it's a variable length string, **define** a length: `@date NVARCHAR(20)` or whatever is suitable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line is executing the stored procedure. There it is missing the parameters.

```
exec SaveOneTimeDonation
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I have just started learning stored procedures.  I have solved the problem by removing the last line.  Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedure is with parameters so at the end you should give parameters when you try to execute it.